# Finding and piecing together dispersed words in a character array

Tags: java

I am trying to search through an array of characters such as: X X F X N A N X J S D
and print out the word FAN. We can assume that the puzzle will change and the word will change, and I'm really just trying to figure out conceptually how to do this search.

My initial plan was to iterate through the characters, but I have no clue how to check and compare the characters in the character array with the word fan.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Do the letters need to be in order within the scrambled array? For example, F must come before A in the scrambled array?

Comment: Yes, F will come before A in the scrambled array. They will be in order

Comment: if word contains `F` and word contains `A` .... then print `F` `A` `N` ?

Comment: It has to be more robust than that, I cant assume the word is fan. It can be any word in the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Just search very character of $fan in the array.
Note that except for the first character, the starting position of other character searches is where the previous character has been found in the array +1.

```
def from_index 0

for char c : fan

     find index of c in array from from_index;

     update from_index;


if any charcter not found, end the loop.
```